# Rails: Why images are not showing in my rails basic app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, image

my `index.html.erb` code -

```
<h1>Listing products</h1>

<table border="1">

<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= product.title %></td>
    <td><%= product.description %></td>
    <td><%= image_tag(product.image_url, :class => 'list_image') %></td>
    <td><%= product.price %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', product %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Product', new_product_path %>
```

and images are under `app\assets\images`..but still images are not appearing on front end.

When I `Firebug` it, i believe image tag is correctly forming...let me know what i am missing in this part.

```
<img src="/images/product1.jpg" class="list_image" alt="Product1">
```

**Screenshot** -

[image: screenshot]

Images are in place as well -

[image: image placeholder]

Let me know what I am doing wrong and how do i fix it.

**EDIT**

[github.com/swapnesh/depot](http://github.com/swapnesh/depot)

Let me know why it is not working in my case.

Although changing `/images/product1.jpg` **To** `/assets/product1.jpg` makes it working.

Comment: are you using paperclip or carrierwave?

Comment: are you 100% sure that the file **/app/assets/images/product1.jpg** exists? I'm not sure but the file may not exist and then the helper is using the path **/images/product1.jpg** instead of **/assets/product1.jpg**

Comment: Try editing `src` attribute: `<img src="/images/product1.jpg" class="list_image" alt="Product1">` to `<img src="product1.jpg" class="list_image" alt="Product1">` in firebug

Comment: @codeit the case was as mentioned by skrikant....although I am looking a little detailed answer about this behaviour

Comment: @rorra Yes its thr..and case was well settled by Srikant although looking for little more description :)

Comment: @swapnesh yes I don't understand why **image_tag** creates a path to the **/images** directory and not to **/assets**, it may be something in your configuration files, because it should point to **/assets**

Comment: @rorra let me github it and please let me know what is the issue as I am really interested in knowing about this ..hope you will help me :)

Comment: @rorra Here is the link ..please check it and let me know what and where I am missing   https://github.com/swapnesh/depot

Comment: I just checked out the code, I added a product with the image url "product2.jpg", and then the code worked totally fine with the **<%= image_tag @product.image_url %>**. If you input the path **/images/product2.jpg** when creating the product, then it will use the relative path, but if you just input **product2.jpg**, it will point to the right asset path. Nevertheless, that's not the way to upload an image to a product, try to check gems like **parperclip**, and I would advise to read the book **agile web development with rails**.

Comment: @rorra I am actually following a book agile-web-development-with-rails and this thing is from the book ....add you comment and statement under answer

Comment: Done, I wrote you a detailed explanation of how assets and image_tag works. You can read the rails guide about it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html. It will help you a lot to understand how the assets works in rails.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you are using asset pipeline http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html,

The image path should be `/assets/product1.jpg` instead of `/images/product1.jpg`

If you are not using asset pipeline, move the images folder to `public/images`

Comment: No. By default image will be searched in `/assets/images/`

Comment: @Srikanth Perfect ..its working when I changed "/images/product1.jpg" ---> "/assets/product1.jpg" ..can you please elaborate your answer as I am new to it(although I checked the URL you mentioned..but something in simple words will be appreciated) +1

Comment: @Swapnesh: You will have to read the Asset pipeline documentation to understand this behaviour. From Rails 3.1 asset pipeline is introduced. Its moving the image, css, js into assets directory and makes the path easier in view file. In View file we just call /assets/product.jpg, /assets/product.css even though its organized in /assets/images/product.jpg, /assets/stylesheets/product.css.  This also enables compressing JS, css, Images on production.

Answer (score 14):

I just checked your application, there is nothing wrong with your code. The only thing is to understand how **image_tag** works.

Usually you put all your images, javscripts and stylesheests on the **app/assets** directory. When you work on the development environment, those files are served uncompressed, but when you deploy to production, the assets are precompiled, minified, and the result files are stored in **public/assets**.

The idea behind minified assets, is just to make the requests faster for the clients, and to save bandwidth.

Now, on the method **image_tag**, you can use an external path for the image, a local path for the image or a relative path for the image.

When you do

```
<%= image_tag "http://www.mywebsite.com/image.jpg" %>
```

it will use the absolute url for the image tag, and you will end with

```
<img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/image.jpg" />
```

You can add a local path as well, like

```
<%= image_tag "/images/image.jpg" %>
```

Which will end in

```
<img src="/images/image.jpg" />
```

which is actually the issue you are having, because rails, when it precompiles the files, it puts everything within **/public/assets**, and you can access those files by going to the path **/assets** as the other users explained.

So the code

```
<%= image_tag "/assets/image.jpg" %>
```

actually works, because you end with

```
<img src="/assets/image.jpg" />
```

The other thing you can do, is to use a relative path, i.e.

```
<%= image_tag "image.jpg" %>
```

that will be converted to

```
<img src="/assets/image.jpg" />
```

and that will work the same the last scenario.

Nevertheless, on your application, you are going to let the users to upload their own images, this will happen later when you advance on the book, on a real world app, you will use a gem like [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave)

Answer (score 1):

As Srikanth already said, the assets path should be referenced. As an example you could put `<%= image_tag 'rails.png' %>` within your code and check firebug (or inspect element within chrome) to check the result.

I'm not quite sure why your code is not working, since I can see you followed Agile Web Development with Rails. I got the depot application running without problems. In your table I see you 'Product1', 'Product2' and 'Product3', is this what you actually filled in within the image_url text_field? What happens if you change 'Product1' to 'product1.jpg'?

On a side note, if you want to use Paperclip, your call should look like this:

```
<%= image_tag(product.image.url, class: 'list_image') %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are received a file with a .jpeg extension try and renaming the file with just the ".jpg".

From

```
<%= image_tag "image.jpeg" %>
```

To:

```
<%= image_tag "image.jpg" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the Agile Web Development With Rails book then there is no problem with the html.erb code. The only issue lies in the scss file. Please check if you have set the td.image display to none! Change display to block and you will see the images.