# Images not displaying when integrating materialize into rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, materialize

I'm trying to integrate materialize into a rails (5.0.3) project. I've put my images (for parallax) into assets folder, images folder in assets, public folder, and an assets folder in public. I cannot get any images to load on my page. Here is html:

```
<div class="parallax"><img src="background1.jpg" alt="Unsplashed background img 1"></div>
```

using gem 'materialize-sass'

any suggestions?

Comment: Can't find a good enough one to flag as a dupe, so fast, but this is probably your problem,... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827763/why-images-are-not-showing-in-my-rails-basic-app

Comment: for some reason, pictures in public folder would not display, but when I put an assets folder in the public folder, put the pictures in that folder and change src path to /assets/pic, it worked. Thanks for the response.

Comment: That is not the correct way, you're losing one of the major advantages of the asset pipeline (asset fingerprinting). You should put them in assets/images, like you had, and use the image_tag helper in the html, which will add the asset fingerprint...

Comment: That's exactly the info I was looking for, thanks for the great info.